# SQL - how hide duplicates Id

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables:

[image]

I need to select all student in a course and are not in course, but not repeat the student. E.g:

I need all students with a course c_id=1

Should show:

s_id: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,..,all

c_id: 1,null,1,null,null,..,all

If I need all student with a course c_id=2

Should show:

s_id: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,..,all

c_id: 2,2,null,null,null,..,all

Or any idea how to show all students in course and not in course?

I thing try:

```
SELECT st.*, co.`c_id` FROM `student` st 
LEFT JOIN `t_stud_cour` co ON st.`s_id` = co.`s_id`
```

But, show all stundent(ok) and repeat student(x)

Comment: Your query is also returning _all_ courses, which should be a big hint to you that you need to add a second condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need a left join, and the "course number" (c_id) condition in the ON clause of the left join

```
select s.s_id, sc.c_id
from student s
left join stu_cour sc on sc.s_id = s.s_id and sc.c_id = 1
```

You'll only need a distinct if a student can be two times on the same course (I doubt this can happen : it would mean, for example, that you would have two times (1, 1) in stud_cour table).

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeb13/3), with sample for c_id = 1 and c_id = 2

Comment: Yes, that right but this is a case different. And it worked perfectly. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct s.s_id, C.c_id, * FROM Student S
LEFT OUTER JOIN Stud_Cour STC ON S.s_id = STC.s_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Course C ON STC.c_id = C.c_id
```